# capistrano failure - where is cap deploy defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

My run of `cap deploy` fails, and I think it's because of a formatting issue.  Here's some output:

```
* executing "rm -rf /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/releases/20101215141011/log /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/releases/20101215141011/public/system /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/releases/20101215141011/tmp/pids &&\\\n      mkdir -p /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/releases/20101215141011/public &&\\\n      mkdir -p /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/releases/20101215141011/tmp &&\\\n      ln -s /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/shared/log /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/releases/20101215141011/log &&\\\n      ln -s /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/shared/system /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/releases/20101215141011/public/system &&\\\n      ln -s /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/shared/pids /var/www/cap-deploy/socialmit/releases/20101215141011/tmp/pids"
```

(Sorry for the formatting.)

The `&&\\\n` things look really fishy, and indeed dumping them into my console causes an output of `\n: command not found.

WHere is `cap deploy` defined?  It looks like the issue has something to do with it being defined as a list of commands that aren't properly formatted, leading to the extraneous newline that is throwing stuff off.  But I can't find the actual code for `cap deploy` to fix it.  It doesn't seem to be an app-specific thing since it's not in my Capfile or any of the files referenced by the Capfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that some user-defined tasks named `after_symlink` had to be renamed and invoked after the symlink using the `after("deploy:symlink", "deploy:new_name")` syntax:

problem:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Symlink the upload directories"
  task :after_symlink do
    #run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/uploads"
    run "ln -s #{deploy_to}/shared/db #{deploy_to}/#{current_dir}/db/link"
  end
end
```

error (actually a warning):

```
Deprecation Warning] Naming tasks with before_ and after_ is deprecated, please see the new before() and after() methods. (Offending task name was after_update_code)
[Deprecation Warning] Naming tasks with before_ and after_ is deprecated, please see the new before() and after() methods. (Offending task name was after_symlink)
```

correct way of doing it:

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc "Symlink the upload directories"
  task :link_db do
    #run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/uploads"
    run "ln -s #{deploy_to}/shared/db #{deploy_to}/#{current_dir}/db/link"
  end
end

after("deploy:symlink", "deploy:link_db")
```

The issue with the `\\\n` business was a misdiagnosis on my part.  Apparently that is executed fine.

Answer (score 0):

The deploy task is defined in the gem [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L156).

I'd say that's most likely not the problem though. What error is it raising when the deploy fails?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Indeed, the problem had to do with capistrano not executing the symlinking command due to it being defined as after_symlink (the convention changed).  Adding more details in a solution below.